# changing plus sign to minus when collapsed while keeping link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm pretty new to jQuery, so I admit I don't fully know what I'm doing. The top menu item is just text and not it's own link, but it has a dropdown. I'm trying to add a plus and minus sign before the text that toggles while keeping the original content clickable.

HTML

```
<div class="menu-clinical-materials">
<ul>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a>Clinical Studies &amp; Articles</a>           
        <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
            <li><a target="_blank" href="">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="">Link 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a>Counseling Sheets</a>         
        <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
            <li><a target="_blank" href="">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a target="_blank" href="">Link 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".menu-item-has-children:has(ul)").prepend("<span class=\"Expander\">+</span>");
    jQuery(".Expander").click(function () {
        jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).html() == "+" ? "-" : "+");
        jQuery(this).toggleClass("Expanded").siblings("ul").slideToggle();
        return false;
    }).eq(0).addClass("Expanded").end().slice(1).siblings("ul").hide();
});
```

So I want "Clinical Studies & Articles" clickable, not just the +/- sign.

[Here's what I have so far](http://jsfiddle.net/homsAU/9gpx9ek2/)

EDIT

I was able to get it to work the way I wanted but using a different method. I'd still like to know how to do this with the .click function instead of toggle though. I'd appreciate it. Here's the fiddle with my workaround
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/homsAU/gru7f5L9/)

Here is the changed JS

```
//<![CDATA[
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery(".menu-item-has-children:has(ul)").prepend("<span class=\"plus-minus\">+</span>");
jQuery(".sub-menu").addClass('expander').hide();
jQuery('.menu-item-has-children').parent().toggle(function () {
    jQuery(".plus-minus").text("-");
    jQuery(".expander").slideDown();
}, function () {
    jQuery(".plus-minus").text("+");
    jQuery(".expander").slideUp();
})
});
```

Comment: Isn't it already working? What seems to be the problem?

Comment: i was trying to get the text to be clickable and not just the plus or minus sign.

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/09yvvsh5/1/

Comment: thanks! you and @rejith-r-krishnan got what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Improved [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/9gpx9ek2/12/). Use [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) to prevent click on inner links to bubble and close the whole block.

```
//<![CDATA[
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".menu-item-has-children:has(ul)").prepend("<span class=\"Expander\">+</span>");

    jQuery(".menu-item-has-children").click(function () {
        buttonText = jQuery(this).children('.Expander').html() == "+" ? "-" : "+";
        jQuery(this).children('.Expander').html(buttonText);
        jQuery(this).children('.Expander')
            .toggleClass("Expanded").siblings("ul").slideToggle();
        return false;
    }).eq(0).slice(1).siblings("ul").hide();
});

//Prevent close on click of inner links.
jQuery(".sub-menu > li").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

//]]>
```

Comment: thanks a bunch! i prefer this to the method i found with my workaround.

Comment: i've noticed a slight bug with this. when implementing, i can get the menu to extend, but when i click one of the sub-links, the menu collapses again. thoughts?

Comment: @homsAU please see the latest edit. use `jQuery(".sub-menu > li > a").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});`

Comment: @RRK, Your above answer is not working on mobile. I tried and when I click on li then minus(-) not displaying.